# Are the vast majority of vegans Vitamin B12 deficient?

Tags: nutrition, vegetarianism

[WebMD reports](http://www.webmd.com/food-recipes/20030618/vegetarian-diet-b12-deficiency):

> In the July issue of the American Journal of Clinical Nutrition, German researchers tracked 174 apparently healthy people living in Germany and the Netherlands.
>
> They found that **92% of the vegans** they studied -- those who ate the strictest vegetarian diet, which shuns all animal products, including milk and eggs -- **had vitamin B12 deficiency**.

That article refers to [this study](http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/78/1/131.long) that states:

> Of the 3 groups, the vegans had the lowest vitamin B-12 status. In subjects who did not consume vitamins, low holotranscobalamin II (< 35 pmol/L) was found in 11% of the omnivores, 77% of the LV-LOV group, and 92% of the vegans.

[This other study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23356638) says:

> Higher rates of deficiency were reported among vegans compared with vegetarians and among individuals who had adhered to a vegetarian diet since birth compared with those who had adopted such a diet later in life.

**Are the vast majority of Vegans Vitamin B12 deficient?**

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11053901 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFFWstlfDRk

Comment: @CountIbis: If that's an answer, please post it in the answer box.

Comment: @RPBCL: You say you've seen claims as high as 93%. Could you post some of these claims so we can see that we are dealing with a notabie claim, and that we are not arguing against a strawman?

Comment: @Oddthinking sure thing, I'll try and find it again soon...

Comment: @Oddthinking [Found this](http://www.webmd.com/food-recipes/20030618/vegetarian-diet-b12-deficiency) which is only 92% of Vegans, and there's no web link to the study at the end of it but I'm almost certain that [this is it.](http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/78/1/131.long) Worth adding to the question body?

Comment: @CountIblis I can't watch that Youtube link, but apart from being a slightly lower percentage, are you posting that study as an affirmative for the question?

Comment: I posted the links so that you can get some pointers from related research. B12 deficiency has to be defined in some way, it may be the case that levels for optimal health should be quite a bit higher than the levels were overt deficiency starts. This means that studies that look into homocysteine levels, and more generally mortality rates are also important. So, basically, you are tackling two problems at once, it's not just how many vegans are below some B12 level, but also how one should choose this level.

Comment: @CountIblis Is there no way to salvage and answer the question as it stands then? Or would you suggest altering it in some way?

Comment: Yes, but it requires some serious study of the literature to get to the bottom of this. I've given some pointers that I would have to look into myself in more detail...

Comment: @Oddthinking Added it, though the sample size is small it may be the source of these claims? Also found [this study](http://www.karger.com/Article/Abstract/176565) claiming 92% vegans had "vitamin B12 levels < 200pg/ml (normal = 200–900 pg/ml)". Though, this study, too, had a pretty small sample size, and is also getting on a bit in age (from early 1980s)...

Comment: @CountIblis I guess what you're suggesting is pretty much the original question then, right? Or are you suggesting the question is asking a bit too much of the Skeptics community, perhaps? (Not attacking, genuinely curious. One of the reasons I'm asking this question in the first place is that I have time here and there to dig up studies, but not enough time for "serious study of the literature to get to the bottom of this", myself. So if there's someone else who's perhaps already done so who can answer... Well, I guess that's what I'm hoping for? :) )

Comment: [52% are deficient in the clinical sense](http://nutritionfacts.org/video/vegan-epidemic/)

Comment: @CountIblis That, perhaps with some added context (i.e. what the "clinical sense" is exactly, and maybe some comparison to non-vegans as a bonus), sounds like a good answer. :) 
I still can't watch videos at the moment so I'll have to take your work for it for now...

Comment: @RPBCL: I think we might be at cross-purposes. When you *ask* a question, we ask nicely for some links to notable claims to show this is a real claim people make, and to make sure the OP hasn't merely misunderstood a joke or other claim. Those links don't have to be to studies. Newspaper articles, popular tweets, political speeches, etc, are all good fodder. (In answers, we expect much better quality sources.)

Comment: Because you have done a good job at researching the info already, you have set a high standard for the answers. They have to provide better references than what you've already provided to support/refute the claim.

Comment: @Oddthinking First thing's first: Thanks for the edits. Undoubtedly, you're helping my rambling in the question be a bit more understandable haha. Second, are you saying that's a bad thing? Or are you just letting me know that because of this, there might be a while before some answers start coming through?

Comment: @RPBCL: No, it isn't a bad thing at all, but I think the chance of you getting an answer is lower - you already found the two obvious papers that would normally be sufficient to provide an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Summary

The evidence about the prevalence of vitamin B<sub>12</sub> deficiency in vegans comes mainly from [this review of studies in EJCN, 2015](https://www.nature.com/articles/ejcn201446/tables/1):

- The results differed widely (2.4-78%) among studies, but **45% of vegans in average** were B<sub>12</sub> deficient, based on low blood B<sub>12</sub> levels.
- **More than 85% of vegans who were not taking B<sub>12</sub> supplements** were B<sub>12</sub> deficient, based on low blood B<sub>12</sub> levels. (Why not 100%? Because, at the time of a study, some participants were on a vegan diet for only 1 or 2 years, which may be too short to develop deficiency).

### Evidence

1) In various studies described in [The prevalence of cobalamin deficiency among vegetarians assessed by serum vitamin B12: a review of literature (EJCN, 2015)](https://www.nature.com/articles/ejcn201446) (summarized in [**Table 1**](https://www.nature.com/articles/ejcn201446/tables/1)), the percent of vegans with  B<sub>12</sub> deficiency (by the criteria of low B<sub>12</sub> (cobalamin) levels, which ranged widely from <95 to <250 pmol/l) were **2.4 to 78%.**

2) In the study mentioned in the question: [Vitamin B-12 status, particularly holotranscobalamin II and methylmalonic acid concentrations, and hyperhomocysteinemia in vegetarians (AJCN, 2003)](https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article/78/1/131/4689908), which included only 29 vegans, 27 of them or 92% were B<sub>12</sub> deficient on the basis of low  *holotranscobalamin II* levels (<35 pmol/l), but only **52%** on the basis of low *cobalamin* levels (<156 pmol/l).

### Lab tests for vitamin B<sub>12</sub> deficiency

According to [Institute of Medicine (US)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK114302/), blood levels of **vitamin B<sub>12</sub> (cobalamin)** that reflect deficiency are 120 to 180 pmol/L (170 to 250 pg/mL) for adults. But, as deficiency develops, blood levels may be maintained at the expense of B<sub>12</sub> in the tissues. Thus, normal blood levels do not necessarily indicate adequate B<sub>12</sub> status.

**Methylmalonic acid (MMA)** levels may more accurately reflect the B<sub>12</sub> status, because they indicate a metabolic change that is highly specific to B<sub>12</sub> deficiency ([Office of Dietary Supplements](https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminB12-HealthProfessional/)). Blood levels <270 nmol/l are normal ([The Vegan Society](https://www.vegansociety.com/resources/nutrition-and-health/nutrients/vitamin-b12/what-every-vegan-should-know-about-vitamin-b12)).

### Time in which vitamin B<sub>12</sub> deficiency can develop

According to [Vegan Society](https://www.vegansociety.com/resources/nutrition-and-health/nutrients/vitamin-b12/what-every-vegan-should-know-about-vitamin-b12):

> In the absence of any apparent dietary supply, deficiency **symptoms**
>   usually take **five years or more** to develop in adults, though some
>   people experience problems **within a year.** A very small number of
>   individuals with no obvious reliable source appear to avoid clinical
>   deficiency symptoms for **twenty years or more.**

The [recommended dietary allowance (RDA)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK114302/) for vitamin B<sub>12</sub> for adults is 2.4 µg/day. It is not clear at which lower daily intakes deficiency could develop, but vegetarians, who consume [milk](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/food-details/336070/nutrients) with 1.1 µg B<sub>12</sub>/cup (237 mL) and [eggs](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-app.html#/food-details/339005/nutrients) with 0.6 µg B<sub>12</sub> also often develop deficiency ([EJCN, 2015](https://www.nature.com/articles/ejcn201446/tables/1)).

### Prevention of vitamin B<sub>12</sub> deficiency in vegans

It seems that for most vegans, the only option to prevent B<sub>12</sub> deficiency is to consume B<sub>12</sub> fortified foods or supplements. Some plant foods contain vitamin B<sub>12</sub>, but this is either inactive (in spirulina, chlorella, tempeh, miso, kombu) or not present in sufficient amounts (in white button mushrooms, Korean purple laver or nori or nutritional yeast); human intestinal bacteria may also produce some vitamin B<sub>12</sub> but not in sufficient amounts ([Vegan Health](https://veganhealth.org/vitamin-b12-plant-foods/), [Vegetarian Nutrition Dietetic Practice Group](https://vndpg.org/docs/rd-resources/B12-RD.pdf)).

### Vitamin B<sub>12</sub> deficiency in vegans who do not take supplements

1. [AJCN, 2003](https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article/78/1/131/4689908), [Table 1](https://academic.oup.com/view-large/109806135): 29% (5 from 17) of vegans who were taking B<sub>12</sub> supplements and **83%** (10 from 12) of those who were not, were B<sub>12</sub> deficient.
2. [Annals of Nutrition and Metabolism, 1983](https://www.karger.com/Article/Abstract/176565): From 83 participants (vegetarians/vegans), **92% of vegans who were not taking supplements,** 64% of the lactovegetarians, 47% of the lacto-ovovegetarians and 20% of the semivegetarians had low serum vitamin B12 levels (<200pg/ml or <150 pmol/L). However, their complete blood count values did not deviate greatly from those found for nonvegetarians (no anemia), even though some had been vegans or lactovegetarians for over 10 years.

Comment: So, a large part of the evidence says "supplementing B12 ~effectivly  prevents deficiency"? The way the claim is framed any analysis *must* look just for strict veganism *without* pills. Although the title seems to look a 'epidemiologically found' this cannot be used to draw any meaningful conclusions, as the veganism that should be under the loupe is a diet, not a pharmaceutical intervention. This looks at veganism as an upper-class capitalist lifestyle. Add to that internal stores: the most interesting point is B12-level in true vegans w/o pharmacy shopping after 20 years of observance.

Comment: "As is" Q is exactly that: not very "interesting", since we look for actual 'unclean' practices.  That is: seeing that B12 caring pillpoppers still have problems is indeed valuable. But I still suggest to really frame-challenge this into two clearly separated sections: 1 looking at self-reported vegans and their confounded status *with* pills 2 actual vegans (zero pills) and their status. (Knowing that the literature on this isn't that ample). Pure veganism is a major challenge in any case.

Comment: I work with a group of boyscouts. There are a few parents on that group that went all-natural vegans (as in, no supplementation of any kind). The difference on their kids towards the non-vegan kids is rather remarkable - they are usually the least energetic, most pale, weak and mentally underdeveloped of the bunch. They are also sick quite often. [This was also observed elsewhere](https://www.healthline.com/health-news/is-a-vegan-diet-safe-for-children#1)

Comment: I do feel this answers my question as I've stated it. Thanks for this researched answer.